# HSQL sequence creation from max id in a cloumn

Tags: java, hibernate, sequence, liquibase, hsqldb

I want to create sequence for max(id) and increment it by 1 in HSQL

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test1_seq [AS {INTEGER | BIGINT}]
    [START WITH (Select max(id) from test)] [INCREMENT BY 1];
```

but it is not working

Comment: If the purpose of the sequence ist to create unique IDs for tuples of your test table you could do that in the Hibernate maping file for your test class: `<id name="ID" type="long">
      <generator class="increment"></generator></id>`

Comment: Is there any possibilities to create procedure in hsql db. at line 2 START WITH accepts numeric value but not the inline select max(id) query

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB supports only constants for both CREATE SEQUENCE ... START WITH and ALTER SEQUENCE ... RESTART WITH statements.

A named SEQUENCE can be used in the CREATE TABLE statement, where it is incremented automatically from the start value:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (id BIGNIT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE test1_seq, ...)
```

Comment: same issue i felt with oracle sequence creation and overcome by writing procedure. Such way I am looking for an option